# Prevent firebug from manipulating DOM

Tags: dom, firebug, dom-manipulation

Is there a way **to prevent programs** like [`Firebug`](http://getfirebug.com/) from manipulating the **DOM** of a page.

I've noticed that you can **simply delete thing like ads** that are paid for by other companies.

Is there a way **for the page to stop it?**

Comment: Why are you picking on Firebug, when there is Adblock Plus whose entire raison d'etre is to delete ads for users automatically?  ;-)

Comment: Firebug is my favorite tool...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you prevent me from switching to another channel on TV, or from cutting away ads from my newspaper? No. Same thing with my PC.

In other words: the page is in the client's computer, and the client can do whatever they wish with it.

Comment: Beautifully worded. I'd upvote this again if I could. (I hate cloud feudalism...)

Comment: @Mchl I think you cherry picking metaphors. What about being able to cut away ads/commercials from a TV programme. You can't. When I filter the bla-bla from your answer nothing more is left but: No, you can't.

Comment: Removing ads from TV programme? Yes you can, for example with: http://tvadblocker.co.uk/ 
And yes, bottom line is 'No, you can't' but the answer needs to be at least 30 characters at SO.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is no.

The long answer: if you construct your ads from many unrelated absolute-positioned elements, it will be next to impossible to delete them.

The right answer: if your ads are so obtrusive that you have to worry about people deleting them, then you should rethink your business.

Comment: I'd go a bit farther: If your business model depends on ad revenue, you need to rethink your business.

Answer (score 2):

Firebug runs in the context of the displayed page, and since pages' scripts can alter dom and delete things, firebug can too.

However you can run some javascript to check if the ad is deleted, and restore it, but still that javascript can be stopped/disabled with firebug.